# LibGDX music doesn't play anymore after x times

Tags: android, libgdx, sound, music

In my App I added two sounds, the first is played when the *gamescreen* start the second when the game is going to *game Over screen*.

Everything works fine but after about 12-13 games the second sound isn't played and until the player close completly the app and open it again every sound isn't played. How to solve?

Errors :

```
05-24 09:04:29.773    5571-5585/ E/AudioTrack﹕ AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
05-24 09:04:29.773    5571-5585/ E/SoundPool﹕ Error creating AudioTrack
05-24 09:04:32.421    5571-5585/ E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-19, 0)
05-24 09:04:32.421    5571-5571/ E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-19,0)
```

Comment: Where was that error shown? Was any other information attached to it?

Comment: @Anko I added the errors, I also set in setOnCompletationListener music.dispose() but it still not working

Comment: You probably should not be creating a new music object every time you need it. Create it once and then store it somewhere. But if it's a very large file and you would rather not store it then make sure to dispose it once you're done with it.